# R: get substring after special charakter

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a R data table with thousands of strings of the following structure:

```
c("123 / and zu gfg",
  "5674 ? 34-ggf gfg",
  "5674 - 56-ggfg g gfg",
  "1389 ?? 8,7-opg g gfg")
```

I want to extract in a column of a DT

1. the special character after the number (/-? Or ??)
2. B) the complete substring after the special character (might contain - or space or other special characters itself)

I fail to get the special character. Is there a general way to adress those?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use `dput` i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))`.  as it is not clear about the quotes here

Comment: For the strings :

c("123 / and zu gfg",
  "5674 ? 34-ggf gfg",
  "5674 - 56-ggfg g gfg",
  "1389 ?? 8,7-opg g gfg")

Output 1.)

"/", "?", "-", "??"

Output 2.)

"and zu gfg",
  "34-ggf gfg",
  "56-ggfg g gfg",
  "8,7-opg g gfg"

Answer (score 1):

```r
vec <- c("123 / and zu gfg", "5674 ? 34-ggf gfg", "5674 - 56-ggfg g gfg", "1389 ?? 8,7-opg g gfg")

sub("^[0-9]+\\s+(\\S+)\\s?.*", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "/"  "?"  "-"  "??"

sub("^[0-9]+\\s+(\\S+)\\s?(.*)", "\\2", vec)
# [1] "and zu gfg"    "34-ggf gfg"    "56-ggfg g gfg" "8,7-opg g gfg"
```

or as two columns of a frame, one regex pass:

```r
strcapture("^[0-9]+\\s+(\\S+)\\s?(.*)", vec, list(a="", b=""))
#    a             b
# 1  /    and zu gfg
# 2  ?    34-ggf gfg
# 3  - 56-ggfg g gfg
# 4 ?? 8,7-opg g gfg
```